# Reinitialize a session variable in java

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

i am declare a session on login time when page goes to other servlet i want change the value or session .. it contain the boolean type variable like true or false but when page return from servlet on jsp ..  i am print the value of session so its contain fiest false which is the value of login time ang second is true which is second servelt [image: Like this the output]

on login servlet i am creating the session veriable

```
 session.setAttribute("check_insRow_button", false);
```

on second

```
  session.setAttribute("check_insRow_button", true);
```

Comment: I am not able to understand your question quite well.

Comment: i want change the value of session on second servlet

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the value of `check_insRow_button` in second servlet, you can directly get the `HttpSession` object and set value when it is called.

So in your first servlet, in your `doGet` or `doPost` method depending on what you are calling.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("check_insRow_button",true);
```

and when you navigate to another servlet from this, again same thing

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("check_insRow_button",true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reinitializing the session variable, you can first remove that attribute and create it again as:

```
session.removeAttribute("check_insRow_button");
session.setAttribute("check_insRow_button", true);
```

Comment: check if that attribute is null or not by session.getAttribute() method. If it is null, then its fine; you can create new session attribute. But if it is not null, then remove that attribute first and then create it again. This should work. If not working still, then error is somewhere else.

Comment: first time it contain the false .. when i click on the submit button and page go to servlet than i want to change the value of session but it display both .. again and again i also try this bt i got same out put